# Convert string list to original python list in specified format

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list

I am reading a line from the text file: The text file looks like this:

```
  2 [209:0.3720511,256:0.3525813,300:0.3466443,148:0.3456179,246:0.3443979,267:0.3425797,126:0.3397026,10:0.3379505,266:0.3357508,301:0.334953]
```

I am trying to convert `[209:0.3720511,256:0.3525813,300:0.3466443,148:0.3456179,246:0.3443979,267:0.3425797,126:0.3397026,10:0.3379505,266:0.3357508,301:0.334953]` in list containing values `[209,256,300,148,246,267...]`

I followed this link : [Convert string representation of list to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list)

Here is my code but it's not working:

```
  with open("file.txt", "r") as text_file:
  for line in itertools.islice(text_file, 19, 20): # only one line
     print(ast.literal_eval(line.split("    ")[1]))
```

giving error.

Please help.

Comment: `[209:0.3720511,256:0.3525813,300:0.3466443,148:0.3456179,246:0.3443979,267:0.3425797,126:0.3397026,10:0.3379505,266:0.3357508,301:0.334953]` is not a valid python list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A colon is not part of a valid number in Python. Therefore, `ast.literal_eval` is inappropriate.

Instead, you can use a list comprehension combined with `str.split` and slicing:

```
x = '[209:0.3720511,256:0.3525813,300:0.3466443,148:0.3456179,246:0.3443979,267:0.3425797,126:0.3397026,10:0.3379505,266:0.3357508,301:0.334953]'

res = [int(i.split(':')[0]) for i in x[1:-1].split(',')]

# [209, 256, 300, 148, 246, 267, 126, 10, 266, 301]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I take the **exact** string you have provided me:

- split by space
- take last item
- replace problematic items [ ] with { }
- do literal evaluation **literal_eval**  =  output python dict

  ```
  line_fixed = literal_eval(line.split(' ')[-1].replace('[', '{').replace(']', '}'))
  print (line_fixed.keys() )
  print (line_fixed.values() )
  ```